# No penalty for hitting catcher in the head with a bat?

Tags: rules, baseball

In game 4 of the World Series last night I noticed that in the 4th inning, one of the Dodger batters, the second one I think, hit the catcher in the head with his bat. Is there no penalty for this?

Answer (score 2):

Manny Machado's follow-through hit the Red Sox catcher once in the series, and Xander Bogaerts did the same to the Dodgers' catcher.  In either case, these were incidental contacts and a simple apology was given to the catcher.  No punitive ruling was assessed, and none would be.

When it becomes an issue is if a baserunner goes to steal a base.  If in this case, the batter has the same contact, the baserunner is called out due to interference.

In a more extreme case, when the umpire rules there has been malicious contact, the batter is ejected.  While I have not seen a batter maliciously hit a catcher with a bat, I have seen on two occasions a batter kick the catcher before charging the mound